# How to suppress File in use alert message

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the below codes in excel VBA to update the database from excel form. after using `Application.Displayalert = False` and `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` also i'm still getting the **File in use** alert message.

```css
Private Sub B_Save_Click()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

path = "Z:\General\"
wbnam = "Data Base_2018.xlsb"
Workbooks.Open Filename:=path & wbnam, WriteResPassword:="Magellan7", ReadOnly:=False

Set Dest = ActiveWorkbook

If Dest.ReadOnly Then
Dest.Close
MsgBox "Someone currently updating UM. Please try again later.", vbInformation
Exit Sub
End If

mon = WorksheetFunction.Text(TB_Date.Text, "mmm")

Set Destsht = Dest.Sheets(mon)

Destsht.Activate
lrow = Destsht.Cells(Destsht.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lrow = lrow + 1

Cells(lrow, ukey).Value = Trim(CB_Key.Text)
Cells(lrow, ud).Value = Trim(TB_Date.Text)
txt = Trim(CB_Name.Text)

Cells(lrow, uact).Value = Trim(CB_Activity.Text)
Cells(lrow, qa).Value = Trim(CB_QAfor.Text)

Cells(lrow, utrac).Value = Trim(TB_Track.Text)
Cells(lrow, usit).Value = Trim(TB_Site.Text)
Cells(lrow, utim).Value = Trim(TB_Time.Text)

Cells(lrow, acat).Value = Trim(val(TB_Act_Cat.Text))
Cells(lrow, atag).Value = Trim(val(TB_Act_Tag.Text))
Cells(lrow, aval).Value = Trim(val(TB_Act_Val.Text))
  
Cells(lrow, rcnt).Value = Trim(val(TB_Reso.Text))

Cells(lrow, alcat).Value = Trim(TB_Al_Cat.Text)
Cells(lrow, altag).Value = Trim(TB_Al_Tag.Text)
Cells(lrow, alval).Value = Trim(TB_Al_Val.Text)
  
MsgBox "UM udpated successfully", vbInformation

Dest.Close savechanges:=True

End Sub
```

Why i'm getting it?  How can i suppress it?

Comment: You cannot surpress this kind of message with setting DisplayAlerts to false. You need to check if the file is open, you could use the following function https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291295/macro-code-to-check-whether-a-file-is-already-open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of your code

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:=path & wbnam, WriteResPassword:="Magellan7", ReadOnly:=False

Set Dest = ActiveWorkbook

If Dest.ReadOnly Then
Dest.Close
MsgBox "Someone currently updating UM. Please try again later.", vbInformation
Exit Sub
End If
```

You would write

```
   Path = "Z:\General\"
    wbnam = "Data Base_2018.xlsb"
    fileName = Path & wbnam

    If IsFileOpen(fileName) Then
        MsgBox "Someone currently updating UM. Please try again later.", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set dest = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=fileName, WriteResPassword:="Magellan7", ReadOnly:=False)
```

And you need to add the function IsFileOpen from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291295/macro-code-to-check-whether-a-file-is-already-open)

```
Function IsFileOpen(fileName As String)
    Dim filenum As Integer, errnum As Integer

    On Error Resume Next   ' Turn error checking off.
    filenum = FreeFile()   ' Get a free file number.
    ' Attempt to open the file and lock it.
    Open fileName For Input Lock Read As #filenum
    Close filenum          ' Close the file.
    errnum = Err           ' Save the error number that occurred.
    On Error GoTo 0        ' Turn error checking back on.

    ' Check to see which error occurred.
    Select Case errnum

        ' No error occurred.
        ' File is NOT already open by another user.
        Case 0
         IsFileOpen = False

        ' Error number for "Permission Denied."
        ' File is already opened by another user.
        Case 70
            IsFileOpen = True

        ' Another error occurred.
        Case Else
            Error errnum
    End Select

End Function
```